# Vanilla JS: How to keep track of an object's properties from another object?

Tags: javascript

I defined a class that acts as a stack, I can push elements to it and undo/redo those elements.

```
export default class Stack {
  constructor() {
    this.history = [];
    this.pointer = -1;
  }

  push(element) {
    this.pointer += 1;
    if (this.pointer < this.history.length) { this.history.length = this.pointer; }
    this.history.push(element);
  }

  undo() {
    if (this.pointer >= 0) {
      // undo element...
      this.pointer -= 1;
    }
  }

  redo() {
    if (this.pointer < this.history.length - 1) {
      this.pointer += 1;
      // redo element...
    }
  }

  isEmpty() {
    return this.history.length === 0;
  }

  canUndo() {
    return !(this.isEmpty() || this.pointer === -1);
  }

  canRedo() {
    return !(this.isEmpty() || this.pointer === this.history.lenght - 1);
  }
...
```

Then I have another object which instantiates a `Stack` object and displays buttons to use the `undo` and `redo` methods; but I need to disable them when these operations can't be performed (I have implemented the methods `canUndo` and `canRedo` in `Stack` to validate this)

I can disable the buttons when I initialize them, but I don't know how can I call the `canUndo` and `canRedo` methods every time the stack properties are changed, so I can disable/enable them dinamically. What would be the best approach for this?

NOTE: The buttons are drawn in a canvas, they're not normal HTML elements. I'm using ES6 and **no frameworks** for this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can make `canUndo` and `canRedo` a flag in the state of your Stack.  Then conditionally render your buttons as disabled based on the state of `stack.canUndo` or `stack.canRedo`.

```
  constructor() {
    this.history = [];
    this.pointer = -1;
    this.canUndo = false;
    this.canRedo = false;
  }
```

Just add a bit of logic in your `canUndo` and `canRedo` methods that toggles the flag if you're going from a canUndo state to a cantUndo state.

```
canUndo() {
  const isPossible = !(this.isEmpty() || this.pointer === -1);
  this.canUndo = isPossible;
  return isPossible;
}
```

If you did it this way then external things using the stack could just read the properties of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a listener pattern:

```
class Listener {
  constructor(){
    this.listeners = new Map();
  }
  on(name, func ){
    if(! this.listeners.has(name)){
      this.listeners.set(name,[func]);
    }else{
      this.listeners.get(name).push(func);
    }
  }
  trigger(name,...values){
   const l = this.listeners.get(name);
   if(!l) return;
   l.forEach( func => func(...values) );
  }
}
```

So one can do:

```
class Stack extends Listener {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
  //in every method that enables the undo state
  this.trigger("undo",true);
  //in every method that enables the undo state
  this.trigger("undo",false);
  //in every method that enables the redo state
  this.trigger("redo",true);
  //in every method that disables the redo state
  this.trigger("redo",false);
}
```

And then, if you want dynamic buttons for example one can do:

```
const events = new Stack();

events.on("redo", state => {
  const button = document.getElementById("redo");
  button.disabled = ! state;
});
```